# SQLite: how to concatenate JOIN

Tags: python, sql, list, sqlite, inner-join

I have three tables in my database, related to physical exercises:

```
exercises(id, name)

tags(id, name)

exercises_tags(id_exercise, id_tag)
```

The `exercises_tags` table stores which tags corresponds to which exercise. One exercise can have multiple tags.

Example:

```
exercises(id, name):
(1, 'squat')

tags(id, name)
(1, 'legs')
(2, 'quads')
(3, triceps)

exercises_tags(id_exercise, id_tag)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
```

I want a query that, for a given exercise name, it returns the corresponding tag names, in the example input: `squat`; output = `['legs', 'quads']` . I know how to get the exercise `id` in a query and the corresponding `id_tag` in another query, but I don't know how to put all together and get the final result. I think I have to use `JOIN`, but I don't know how to perform two `JOIN`s.

Comment: Do you want the result as a json array?

Comment: I would prefer a Python list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you join all 3 tables you will get all the rows of `tags` that are related to the input exercise.
Python's `fetchall()` will return these rows as a list of sublists.
Each sublist will contain only 1 item and by extracting all these items in a `for` loop you can get the result as a list:

```
db = 'database_name.db'

con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con.cursor()

sql = """
    SELECT t.name
    FROM exercises AS e
    INNER JOIN exercises_tags AS et ON et.id_exercise = e.id
    INNER JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = et.id_tag
    WHERE e.name = ?;
"""
list = [item[0] for item in cur.execute(sql, ('squat', )).fetchall()]

print(list)
```

It will print:

```
['legs', 'quads']
```